# Need help accessing the specific value of an array in a seperate method

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, parameters, indexof

I need help accessing an array's specific value within a separate method.  During this program I am supposed to write a program that will ask the user to enter rainfall amounts for each month of a calendar year. The program will then determine total annual and average monthly rainfall amounts and finally will allow the user to search for a specific amount.

I am supposed to do this for the last method:  `SearchForAmounts()` – this method will be a void method and have two double arrays for the parameter
list, one for the rainfall amount array and one for the array with the months. It will ask the user for a rainfall amount to search for in the array. It will then either report back in which month that amount first fell or it will
report that no rain of that amount fell that year. It will use one of the Array class methods to determine what to output. It will do this twice in the method – i.e. will repeat the code twice in the method.

I am having troubles finding a way to access the value in the `monthInTheYear` array.  Here is my code:

```
namespace CJohnson_Prog8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] monthInTheYear;
            double[] rainfallAmmounts;

            monthInTheYear = new string[12] { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
            rainfallAmmounts = new double[12];

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Annual Rainfall Program");
            GetRainFall(rainfallAmmounts, monthInTheYear);

            PrintAmounts(rainfallAmmounts, monthInTheYear);
            TotalYearRain(rainfallAmmounts);
            SearchForAmounts(rainfallAmmounts, monthInTheYear);

        }

        public static void GetRainFall(double[] rainfall, string[] month)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rainfall.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the rainfall in inches in {0}: ", month[i]);
                rainfall[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                while (rainfall[i] < 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter the rainfall in inches in {0}: ", month[i]);
                    rainfall[i] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }

        public static void PrintAmounts(double[] rainfall, string[] month)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rainfall.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t\t{1:F2}", month[i], rainfall[i]);
            }
        }

        public static double TotalYearRain(double[] totalrainFall)
        {
            double averageRainFall;
            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < totalrainFall.Length; i++)
            {
                sum += totalrainFall[i];
            }
            averageRainFall = sum / 12;
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Total Annual Rain is: {0:F2}", sum);
            Console.WriteLine("Average Month Rain:  {0:F2}", averageRainFall);
            return sum;
        }

        public static void SearchForAmounts(double[] searchRainFall, string[] searchMonths)
        {


                Console.Write("Enter a rainfall amount to search for: ");
                double RainFall = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


                if (Array.IndexOf(searchRainFall, RainFall) != 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(searchMonths[i] + " was the first month to have " + RainFall + " inches fell this year.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rainfall of " + RainFall + " inches fell that year.");
                }

        }



        }
    }
```

Comment: Please let me know if there is anything I can do to clear this question up for people that may view it.  I am patiently waiting at my computer for a suggestion.  Thank you all who help!

Comment: Try `Array.IndexOf(searchRainFall, RainFall) > -1` and then use the returned index

Comment: So are you saying to portray it like this?:                                                     if (Array.IndexOf(searchRainFall, RainFall) > -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" was the first month to have " +                            RainFall + " inches fell this year.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rainfall of " + RainFall + " inches fell that year.");
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
    //do stuff
    var index = Array.IndexOf(searchRainFall, RainFall);
    if (index > -1) {
        Console.WriteLine(searchMonths[index] + " was the first month to have " + RainFall + " inches fell this year.");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("No rainfall of " + RainFall + " inches fell that year.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so that worked do you have any suggestions on how to make it loop through that twice as stated in the description of this method??? P.S. Thank you.

Comment: I am trying a for loop but it keeps repeating infinitely.

Comment: OK, I added a for loop